# Ostream overloading operator on a linked list

Tags: c++

I have a polynomial implementation in a linked list and want to do `std::ostream` overloading operation but it gives my an error that `no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘std::cout << p5’`

That's my implementation but when I test it through `cout << p5` I get the aforementioned error.

UPDATE:
header file:

```
struct term{
    double coef;
    unsigned deg;
    struct term * next;
};
class Polynomial {
public:
    constructors etc
    overloading functions
   friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out,const term& object);
}
```

then in other file poly.cpp i have:

```
 ostream & operator << (ostream& out, const Polynomial object){
        term* q = object.getptr();
        if (object.getptr() == NULL)
            out << "( )";
        else
            while(q != NULL)
            {
                out << q->coef << "x^" << q->deg << " ";
                q = q->next;
            }
        return out;
    }
```

in main.cpp
Polynomial p5, then added some terms and `cout << p5` but I get errors.

Comment: What is the declaration of `p5`? (Aside: you might prefer `const Polynomial& object` instead of `const Polynomial object`. But that's unrelated to your question.)

Comment: @Robᵩ it *might* not be unrelated.

Comment: Yeah, I see your answer now. But I wonder if that error would generate the posted error message.

Comment: @Robᵩ I've seen weirder. :)

Comment: sorry I actually am passing by reference, but p5 is just a declaration of Polynomial p5, which ten i added some terms into it and cout<<p5 doesn't work giving me the error above, and when passing by reference &p5 it gives me an address

Comment: Post the declaration of `p5` and the definition of `Polynomial`.

Comment: Polynomial is a class and then i add some term like p5.insert() etc

Comment: @JackF is the declaration of the operator visible?

Comment: yes, and it is actually a fried. i used an debugger and it says ': Invalid operands to binary expression ('ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'Polynomial')'

Comment: Where is the function actually *defined*. Can it be "seen" by the rest of the code? Is it in a block? Can you edit your post with more visual context please?

Comment: -1 the problematic code not shown

Comment: What is `term`? Is it another class other than `Polynomial`?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf it is now showed more explicitly, and previously it was stated

Comment: Did my answer actually help? Are you still having problems?

Comment: @David it did help, it works now, why people are giving me so much negative

Comment: Well, the question *was* a bit ambiguous. We couldn't tell what the problem was by the initial code, so the question was not constructive and "[couldn't] be reasonably answered in its current form".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's your declarations which are causing the problem:

```
friend ostream & operator << (ostream & out, const term & object);
```

and

```
ostream & operator << (ostream & out, const Polynomial & object);
```

These don't match. One is using a `term` object and the latter is using a `Polynomial` object. I'm assuming you want this function to use a term object because the function uses data memebers specific to the struct `term`. So change the latter to accept a `term` object:

```
ostream & operator << (ostream & out, const term & object);
```

Comment: yes that was it, thank you so much, such a stupid mistake causing me couple of hours